# How to style element width % using ng-style

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to style my progress bar using with percentages but following ng documentation I can't seem to grasp it. It should be 20% with, but it's 100% (default).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u6xp8csh/

Here is what I have tried

#### HTML

```
<div data-ng-app>
    <div data-ng-controller="ProgressBarController">
        <div class="progress-bar-container">
            <div class="progress-bar" ng-style="{'width' : '{{ progress }}'% }">{{ progress }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### JS

```
function ProgressBarController($scope) {
    $scope.progress = 20;
}
```

#### CSS

```
.progress-bar-container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.progress-bar {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`progress` field accessible without `'{{'`:

```
 ng-style="{'width' : progress + '%' }"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gc343w7x/

Answer (score 5):

The inside of the ng-style is stripped down Javascript, so you have a string `'{{progress}}'` immediately followed by the modulus operator `%`.

```
ng-style="{width: progress + '%'}"
```

will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Move the `%` inside of the quotes.

```
ng-style="{'width' : '{{ progress }}%' }">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <p class="bar" [style.width.%]="value">
        <span>Helo The World</span>
    </p>
```

[For More Detailes click here](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3292-using-percent-for-in-line-styles-in-angular-4-2-3.htm)

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to OP's problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.